# Page not found (404) Request Method: GET

Tags: python, django

I keep getting this error:

- Page not found (404)
- Request Method:   GET
- Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/home
  Using the URLconf defined in `personal_portfolio.urls`, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

`admin/`

`home/`
The current path, home, didn't match any of these.

---

This is my `urls.py` for the overall project

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/', include('hello_world.urls')),
]
```

this is my code for `hello_world urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from hello_world import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', views.hello_world, name='hello_world'),
]
```

this is my code for `hello_world` `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def hello_world(request):
    return render(request, 'hello_world.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to change this url from

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', views.hello_world, name='hello_world'),
]
```

to

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.hello_world, name='hello_world'),
]
```

to get to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/`

else you need to goto `http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/home/` for the current url

Comment: thank you, that's helpful but why would we need two 'home/' for it to be the correct url?