# Page not found, request method: get using Django when all pages correctly in urls.py

Tags: python, django

I know there are many similar posts, but having tried:

[Page not found (404) Request Method: GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61053081/page-not-found-404-request-methodget)

[Django -Page not found (404) Request Method: GET Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61208509/django-page-not-found-404-request-methodget-method)

[Page not found (404) Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67362600/page-not-found-404-request-methodget-request-urlhttp-127-0-0-18000-abou)

I'm still not able to solve this problem. This is a practice sample from cs50w.
I get this error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Using the URLconf defined in airline.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
flights/
users/
The empty path didn’t match any of these.
```

I have a main urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("flights/", include("flights.urls")),
    path("users/", include("users.urls"))
]
```

urls.py in flights:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("<int:flight_id>", views.flight, name="flight"),
    path("<int:flight_id>/book", views.book, name="book")
]
```

and in users, url.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout")
]
```

My settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for airline project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'rf(az43up-jxv^%y9_^z!*bkl=vh-7nz*)!5olp!^&675i@k(x'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'flights',
    'users',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'airline.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'airline.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.AutoField'

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And my views.py in flights:

```
from django import forms
from django.http import HttpResponseBadRequest, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Flight, Passenger

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, "flights/index.html", {
        "flights": Flight.objects.all()
    })


def flight(request, flight_id):
    try:
        flight = Flight.objects.get(id=flight_id)
    except Flight.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Flight not found.")
    return render(request, "flights/flight.html", {
        "flight": flight,
        "passengers": flight.passengers.all(),
        "non_passengers": Passenger.objects.exclude(flights=flight).all()
    })

def book(request, flight_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            passenger = Passenger.objects.get(pk=int(request.POST["passenger"]))
            flight = Flight.objects.get(pk=flight_id)
        except KeyError:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest("Bad Request: no flight chosen")
        except Flight.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest("Bad Request: flight does not exist")
        except Passenger.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest("Bad Request: passenger does not exist")
        passenger.flights.add(flight)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("flight", args=(flight_id,)))
```

and my views.py in users is:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("login"))
    return render(request, "users/user.html")

def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else:
            return render(request, "users/login.html", {
                "message": "Invalid credentials."
            })
    else:
        return render(request, "users/login.html")

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return render(request, "users/login.html", {
        "message": "Logged out."
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is very clear:

> The empty path didn’t match any of these.

In your main `urls.py` you don't have a view for empty path:

```py
# bad
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("flights/", include("flights.urls")),
    path("users/", include("users.urls"))
]
```

To set a view to empty path do you need something like:

```py
# good
from django.urls import include, path
from apps.main import views as main_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', main_views.homepage),  # <--- here your home page view
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("flights/", include("flights.urls")),
    path("users/", include("users.urls"))
]
```

This is the reason that when you are accessing to home page `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` a 404 not found error is raised.

Comment: Yes,Also Katie when you are using `include` the emply path " " in users urls.py  will turn to `127.0.01:8000/users/` which is  != `127.0.01:8000/` . Also set `APPEND_SLASH = False` in settings only if you run into any errors regarding `/` being there at the end. You need to do it like @dani mentioned.

Comment: Thank you so much @dani herrera and also Dushyant Deshwal. This is so helpful. Django has been a slow learn for me

Comment: This should mean I add a  ```main_views.py``` file into the parent folder, then I'd add a ```templates\parent_name\index.html```   and render ``index.html``` from ```main_views.homepage```?

Comment: No, you can assign a view from any file. Just import it .